# Insert / delete content into contenteditable element at given position

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I would like to apply insertion or deletion operation to a content-editable element. Example:

```
element = $('.content')
op = {insert: 'This works', pos:32}

applyOperation(element, op)
```

Would transform:

```
<div class='content'><i>anything</i> something else <i>anything else</i></div>
```

Into:

```
<div class='content'><i>anything</i> something else This works<i>anything else</i></div>
```

Constraint: I would like to avoid full content replacement.

Note: don't bother with HTML validity and selection / carret position for now, I'll take care of that.

Comment: So the position has to be relative to some HTML serialization of the contents of the div? That's going to be impractical.

Comment: You are right. What kind of positioning solution would you suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I write this function for you:

```
/**
 * @author Georgi Naumov
 * gonaumov@gmail.com
 * http://georgi-naumov.blogspot.com/
 **/
function applyOperation(element, op) {
   if(typeof op['insert'] != 'undefined' && typeof op['pos'] != 'undefined') {
       var resultHtml = element.html().replace(new RegExp("((?:[^\s]|[\s]+){" + op['pos'] + "})"), "$1" + op['insert']);
       element.html(resultHtml);
       return element;
   }
}
```

Here is working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zono/qY5yg/

Comment: As stated in my question, I would like to avoid full content replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I have done lot of researches. The answer is: it's pretty tough to achieve in a non-destructive way.

However, James Padolsey wrote [two excellent articles](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-its-not-that-simple/) on that matter, the second one bringing [an answer](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-solved/). And made [a lib](https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText) for everybody to use.

The solution involve getting down to text nodes splitting and merging (through `normalize()`). Really good stuff.